# Removing part of a filesystem partition

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to remove parts of my file system partition of 127 GB What could i try. I don't want to try anything on my own because i'm afraid i might destroy my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which operating system and version of OS are you using. Please [edit]() your question and add the new information **inside the original question**. We need more details of your partitions, how many are there, where they are located, how they are formatted etc. It is better if you can take a screenshot of the app Gparted showing the drive you want to change. Upload the screenshot in imagur.com and add a link to the picture in your question.

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to accomplish. Are you running out of disk space? Need more details.

Comment: heynnema, i am trying to add a new 30 gigabyte filesystem for my lfs system

Comment: Is this Ubuntu? What version? What is lfs system?

Comment: now i figured it out, But it is saying /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck. I used its advice on the busybox thing that appears, But i think the whole file system is corrupted